# What is the Probability that Exactly One Pair among Three Integers is Coprime

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

Given three positive integers $a,b,c$ it isn't difficult to show that
$$
P(\gcd(a,b,c)=1) = \prod_{p}\left(1-p^{-3}\right)=\frac1{\zeta(3)}
$$
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. For the next problems I define the events $A_p=\{a\in\mathbb{N}:p|a\},$ $B_p=\{b\in\mathbb{N}:p|b\},$ $C_p=\{c\in\mathbb{N}:p|c\}$. I call $P_n$ the probability that exactly $n$ out of the three pairs $(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)$ are coprime. Using $A_p,B_p,C_p$ I can show
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_3 &= \prod_{p} \left(1+\frac2p\right)\left(1-\frac1p\right)^2
\\
P_2 &= \prod_{p} \left(1+\frac1p-\frac1{p^2}\right)\left(1-\frac1p\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
but I can't get $P_1$ or $P_0$ in a similar form. In fact, it seems like it's impossible to derive either of $P_1$ and $P_0$ from $A_p,B_p,C_p$ and their compliments. How would you derive a product definition for $P_1$ and $P_0$ like $P_3$ and $P_2$ have above?

Comment: Note that if none of the pairs are coprime, that doesn't mean that $ \gcd(a, b, c) \neq 1$. EG $a = 2 \times 3, b = 3 \times 5, c = 5 \times 2$.  So $ P_0 \neq 1 - P(\gcd(a, b, c) = 1)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Has anyone done the calculation for the probability that three integers are pairwise coprime rather than jointly coprime?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I'm not familiar enough with the literature to give an opinion. There is enough wonky bits about this writeup, then I think it needs to be overhauled.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for pointing that out, I didn't even notice; I'll remove the line.